# How multiple user can work on same file in TFS2010

Tags: .net, tfs

I am using TFS2010 in which i am facing issue like, if i am working on a particular file then at the same time if my other team member is trying to work on then it does not allow to work and throw an error message that: this particular file is already locked by other user and u cant edit this file.Is this a limitation of TFS2010 or some admin permission is required to be given to all the user in my team by admin.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable multiple check-out for your team project under Source Control settings.

> To configure checkout settings In Team Explorer, select the team
> project for which you want to configure check-out settings.
>
> 1. From the Team menu, click Team Project Settings, and then click Source Control.
> 2. In the Source Control Settings dialog box, select the Check-out
>    Settings tab.
> 3. Select or clear the Enable multiple checkout box. Select
>    or clear the Enable get latest on check-out box.
> 4. Click OK.

Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, please be aware that TFS 2010 is no longer supported by Microsoft. Upgrading to a modern version or migrating to Visual Studio Team Services is strongly advised.